# Running a javascript commands only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these 2 javascript commands that practically clicks on the first link in my table, the script works fine, but it continues with an endless loop, while I want this to execute one time and then stop. How can I achieve this?

That's the script:

```
<script>
   $link = $('td a:first');
   $link[0].click();
</script>
```

Comment: The code above does not loop, unless the link in question is to the same document. If it is, you'll need session storage or local storage or similar to flag up that you're doing a subsequent load.

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: The link in question is to the same document, that's why I don't know how to stop it from an endless loop.

Comment: In that case, @T.J.Crowder has answered your question.

Comment: I don't know how to achieve the local storaging or how to flag up that I'm doing a subsequent load.

Comment: so, you mean by clicking the link, you want to reload the some page ?
It's better if you added the function executed by click event

Comment: Basicly I'm in a page like www.sitename.com/blablabla, and the script is clicking to the page www.sitename.com/blablabla?eventID=1231

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve by this?  There may be a more suitable solution.

Comment: Could you add a class to the link only if you want it followed?  eg `<a href='' class='follow'>..` `$("a.follow")[0].click();` - then, when you render the page, don't add that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need local/session storage for that? You can simply compare link with current url like this:

```
<script>
   var $link = $('td a:first');
   if(window.location.href.indexOf($link.attr('href')) === -1) {
      $link[0].click();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I solved my problem with this code! Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
 function autoHandler(){
    var item = localStorage.getItem("turn");
    if(!item){
        localStorage.setItem("turn","1");
        $link = $('td a:first');
        $link[0].click();
    }
   }

       autoHandler();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sozbepyd/

Comment: I don't know why, but your code isn't working in my case, after the page loads, it doesn't autoclick the first href of the table.

Comment: Can you please try after dubugging? It should work.
Also, to rerun this code.
use localStorage.clear() to reset local storage.

Answer (score 0):

This might help - though I suspect that the looping behaviour mentioned probably arises from the snippet in the questions being called more than once, so it may be the result of other script activity on the page (???).

```
<script>
    window.flag = window.flag || true;
    if (window.flag) {
        $('td a:first')[0].click();
        window.flag = !window.flag;
    }
</script>
```

As I said, might help, might not.  :)

**EDIT IN LIGHT OF COMMENT**

I would suggest using `window.sessionStorage` rather than `window.localStorage` as `localStorage` will persist until/unless the user clears their browser cache.  It depends if you wish to inhibit the event forever on all subsequent visits or just inhibit the behaviour once per session.  If the latter replace `localStorage` with `sessionStorage` in Nitesh's answer.

As both `local-` and `sessionStorage` are Cookie-like features, it's good practice to inform the visitor that information is being stored (Cookie and privacy policy).

Comment: From the comments, it's actually a link to the same page - so reloads the page.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Then the @Nitesh's `localStorage` solution is better.